# Images being pulled from a database, wanting to add a jquery large image hover...Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, database, jquery-plugins

I am trying to accomplish adding a hover over the shirt images (images generated from a database) on each shirt on the home page to make them larger before they click on it to go to the zencart to purchase a shirt. Is this possible?

The website is http://www.10before6.com

I tried using this jquery script: http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

but was unable to get it work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hi Jessica!  Welcome to stack overflow!

the link for yourwebsite goes to a broken page.

Can you show us what code you've tried?

Comment: Sorry I had broke the site and I thought the reload was complete before I posted this.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to grow the image on hover, and not use a new image, you can do something like this:

```
$('#yourImage').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({     
        width: 400,     
        height: 400    
    }, 1000);
});
```

That will grow the image on hover. You can add another function to the `hover` event which will run when the cursor moves off the element.

Note that your images will need to be positioned absolutely for this to work without pushing your other content around as the image grows.

See an example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Kbjkz/1/).

Comment: Do you mean the image has already been pulled from the database, or you want to pull a new image from the database when you hover over the current image? This will work on any image that is in the DOM.

Comment: On the home page the images are being pulled from the database, and I want to make those images hover, the site is written in php too, with just a bit of html.

Comment: This should still work fine. You just need to add this jQuery to the page, give images you want to expand a `class`, and change the jQuery selector (`#yourImage`) to the name of the class (e.g. `.yourClass`). Then, whenever you hover over any image with that class, it will expand.

Answer (score 0):

write a piece of javascript like this

```
$("#MyImageID").live("hover", function{}(
   $.post("RestfulServiceURL", function (data){
      $("#HoverDiv").html(data); 
   });
)};
```

Data is the link of the larger image. If its being pulled from the database you have to create a mvc method that kicks out the mime type of an image, or use a ashx file, or resful wcf service to serve up the image.